# How can I make A future of future into one future object?

Tags: java, scala, sequence, akka, future

Env: Akka 2.1, scala version 2.10.M6, JDK 1.7,u5

Now is my problem:
 I have:

```
future1 = Futures.future(new Callable<Future<object>>(){...});
future2 = ? extends Object;
Future.sequence(future1, future2).onComplete(...)
```

now in first line, I have a future of Future of object, is there any way to convert it into a Future while not blocking my current thread?

Is there any method in akka? As far as I checked, I havn't found any yet...
First time to have a post....Sry for bad format and organize... :~P

Comment: This doesn't look like Scala. Is there a reason for the Scala tag?

Comment: Actually I am using akka 2.1 with scala lib for 2.10... sry for the confusion...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Short answer (English): flatMap dat sh!t

Shorter answer (Scala):

```
flatMap(identity)
```

Shortest answer: (Scala 2.12):

```
flatten
```

Long answer (Java):

```
flatMap(new Mapper<Future<X>>,Future<X>>() {
  @Override public Future<X> apply(final Future<X> f) { return f; }
})
```

Comment: : (...for flatMap, what if I make the inner Future (future1's callable funtion) failed using Futures.failed()? the flatMap would still be called? also, I don't want to recover it as, later I would like to make the future of sequence to be failed also....By the way, I am using java, funny for your English answer...: )

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, easiest is probably just to try it out?

Answer (score 13):

Note: Since [Viktor Klang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227803/viktor-klang)'s 2012 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861335/6309), he recently (March 2016) added in [his blog](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog)  for **scala 2.12**:

### [Missing canonical combinators: `flatten`](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-1.md#missing-canonical-combinators-flatten)

> Are you one of us **[`Future`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)**-users who have grown tired of the old `flatMap(identity)` boilerplate for un-nesting Futures as in:

```
val future: Future[Future[X]] = ???
val flattenedFuture /*: Future[X] */ = future.flatMap(identity)
```

> Then I have some great news for you! Starting with Scala 2.12
>   [`scala.concurrent.Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) will have a flatten-method with the following signature:

```
def flatten[S](implicit ev: T <:< Future[S]): Future[S]
```

> Allowing you to write:

```
val future: Future[Future[X]] = ???
val flattenedFuture /*: Future[X] */ = future.flatten
```

Answer (score -4):

You can create another task

```
Futures.future(new Runnable(){
     // wait for future1
     // wait for future2
     // do something with the results.
});
```

or merge the tasks

```
Futures.future(new Runnable(){
     // do the work future2 would have done.
     // wait for future1
     // do something with the results.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer....but why should we bother to use future when tried to make all the stuff async and say, let'em be executed in one thread??

Comment: It will still be executed in multiple threads (assuming you have a pool of more than one thread) just as it does now.  This won't change the level of concurrency.  If you have a pool of one, you could just use one task for everything and it could be much simpler.

Comment: yes, it would works well but if future1 is something of ,say, as is the problem in the question of the post, like Future<Future<...>>, and this main thread would be blocking such a long time which would be wasteful...and flatMap would make a new Future for Future<Future<...>> and give the call back to the original thread which would save more resources...But thanks for your suggestion any way. : )

Comment: The waste is relatively trivial and using another approach you could waste far more IMHO. Also you don't need to keep wrap the Future objects. There is no reason it wouldn't be a plain future. In fact you could add everything it does into that task so there is not need to return anything at all.